# Interface Builder changes my Button dimensions

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Using Xcode 7.3, I have a stop button (just a 100x100 pixel image, no text) that in my Any,Any size class I have added a center horizontally constraint and then a trailing constraint. This keeps it centered and just a bit off the bottom edge of the screen - which works for most cases.

However for a 4-inch iPhone in landscape, my other elements constrain things and I want to put the button vertically centered and somewhat off the right hand side of the screen.

When I go to the Compact Width, Compact Height class view, add Center Vertically in Container and then choose Update Frames to see the result, IB changes the height of my button from 50 to 300. Why does it do this? I want to keep the image dimensions the same.

Comment: If you want the size to be fixed then add width/height constraints.